# login and sign in form problems

Tags: php, html, pdo, xampp

I have two forms (login/sign in)

Login:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" size="25" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $fn; ?>"/>
  <input type="text" size="25" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $ln; ?>"/>
  <input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $un; ?>"/>
  <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $em; ?>">
  <input type="text" size="25" name="email2" placeholder="Repeat Email" value="<?php echo $em2; ?>"/>
  <input type="password" size="32" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <input type="password" size="32" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password"/><br />
  <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!"/>
</form>
```

sign in:

```
<form>
<center><input type ="text" size="25" name="User_login" id="user_login" placeholder="username"/>
<input type ="password" size="25" name="user_password" id="user_password" placeholder="password"/><br />
<input type ="submit" name="button" id="button" value="login to your account!"/></center>
</form>
```

upon pressing the sign in button or the log in button on either form, I am directed back to the same page (which is what I want) but here is what appears in my address bar:

```
http:// localhost/sites/socialnetwork/User_login=&user_password=&button=login+to+your+account%21#
```

What I want it to be is `http:// localhost /sites/socialnetwork/#`

When typing `http:// localhost/ sites/ socialnetwork/` into the address bar the page comes up perfectly, but as soon as I click the sign in buttons..etc it goes to that first link.

Both links show the same pages but how do I make it so that it doesn't show

`User_login=&user_password=&button` etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forms need a `METHOD` and `ACTION` attribute set.

METHOD should be POST

ACTION should be "some-page-name.php", for example.

Comment: That's completely different from what the OP wants. See `<form action="#" method="post">` the METHOD is defined. And not all forms need an ACTION set to a php page to work.

Comment: For good practice, you should define your `action` and `method` attributes on forms..

Answer (score 0):

Define `POST` method in your html form if you want to hide the data from appending in the URL.

By Default form is submitting via `GET` method so you need to explicitly define it `POST` in your case.

From [Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13)-

The method attribute of the FORM element specifies the HTTP method used to send the form to the processing agent. This attribute may take two values:

- get: With the HTTP "get" method, the form data set is appended to the
  URI specified by the action attribute (with a question-mark ("?") as
  separator) and this new URI is sent to the processing agent.
- post: With the HTTP "post" method, the form data set is included in
  the body of the form and sent to the processing agent.

The "get" method should be used when the form is idempotent (i.e., causes no side-effects). Many database searches have no visible side-effects and make ideal applications for the "get" method.